# Comparing rows from the same column and same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
select em.ClinicCode,pa.ConsultantID,pa.RegCode as MRN, pa.AdmissionID,pa.AdmitDate,bm.PainScoreID,pn.PainScore from v_dbPatientAdmissions pa
inner join v_dbPatientBodyMass bm on bm.AdmissionID=pa.AdmissionID
inner join v_dbPainScores pn on bm.PainScoreID=pn.PainScoreID
inner join v_dbEmpClinicCodes em on em.EmpID=pa.ConsultantID
where pa.ConsultantID=1108
```

That gives the following output:
[image]

I've used inner join to join three tables with the main table 'v_dbPatientAdmissions' , in order to retrieve patients in pain that has been seen by a specific doctor.

I'm trying to retrieve the records of patients that have returned to the clinic in less than 24 hours , I will need to compare two rows from the same column 'AdmitDate' while having the 'MRN' in common , i thought of using Datediff function  but I'm not sure how will i do that when I'm trying to compare rows from the same column

Comment: just a note - you say you join 3 table to your main, but it looks like PainScores is joined to values on Patient Body Mass (bm.PainScoreID=pn.PainScoreID) ... was that what you wanted?

Comment: Desired results would really help.

Comment: i used  (bm.PainScoreID=pn.PainScoreID) to be able to retrieve  the 'PainScore' column from the v_dbPainScores pn table I'm not sure if it's considered joined to values or a table ,

Comment: For the desired results I'm trying to retrieve the patients who has returned to the clinic in less than 24 hours and also in pain (I've already added the PainScore condition)  , so I'll need to compare the  AdmitDate's if the MRN (RegCode) is the same  , i couldn't figure out how to compare two rows from the same column , i hope i was able to explain it well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select p.*
from (select em.ClinicCode, pa.ConsultantID, pa.RegCode as MRN, pa.AdmissionID, pa.AdmitDate, bm.PainScoreID, pn.PainScore,
             lag(pa.AdmitDate) over (partition by pa.RegCode order by pa.AdmitDate) as prev_admitDate,
             lead(pa.AdmitDate) over (partition by pa.RegCode order by pa.AdmitDate) as next_admitDate
     from v_dbPatientAdmissions pa join
          v_dbPatientBodyMass bm
          on bm.AdmissionID = pa.AdmissionID join
          v_dbPainScores pn
          on bm.PainScoreID = pn.PainScoreID join
          v_dbEmpClinicCodes em
          on em.EmpID = pa.ConsultantID
     where pa.ConsultantID = 1108
    ) p
where p.admitdate < dateadd(hour, 24, prev_admitdate) or
      p.admitdate > dateadd(hour, -24, next_admitdate);
```

This assumes that the admissions are for the same `ConsultantID`.  If they can span `consultantId`s, then you would need to remove the `where` clause.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2012+ you can use functions [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and/or [`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Assuming that you need to retrieve only the second record you could use something like this:

```
select 
    em.ClinicCode, 
    pa.ConsultantID,
    pa.RegCode as MRN, 
    pa.AdmissionID,
    pa.AdmitDate,
    bm.PainScoreID,
    pn.PainScore 
from v_dbPatientAdmissions pa
inner join v_dbPatientBodyMass bm on bm.AdmissionID=pa.AdmissionID
inner join v_dbPainScores pn on bm.PainScoreID=pn.PainScoreID
inner join v_dbEmpClinicCodes em on em.EmpID=pa.ConsultantID
where pa.ConsultantID=1108
    and DATEDIFF('hour', 
        LAG(pa.AdmitDate, 1, '1900-01-01') OVER (PARTITION BY pa.RegCode ORDER BY pa.AdmitDate), 
        pa.AdmitDate) < 24
```

I am not sure which field represents unique patient field, but I assume it's `pa.RegCode`.

In order to retrieve previous visit date for the same patient I used `LAG` function:

```
LAG(pa.AdmitDate, 1, '1900-01-01') OVER (PARTITION BY pa.RegCode ORDER BY pa.AdmitDate)
```

I didn't have a chance to run the query so some syntax might be not right, but I hope you get the idea how the data can be retrieved.